# javascript form validation if statements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am building a registration form and I found out that the Safari browser doesn't work with the HTML5 'Required' tag. So I built this Javascript script to ensure that users MUST submit data or the form will not submit.

However, if you enter a username and password, but no email address, the form still submits. (The form doesn't submit if you leave out username and/or password).

So the problem seems to be with the email address part of the script. I don't want the form to submit if the email field is blank.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function ValidateLoginForm()
{
    var username = document.form1.username;
    var password = document.form1.password;
    var email = document.form1.email;



      if (username.value == "")
    {
        alert("Your username wasn't recognised.");
        username.focus();
        return false;
    }

      if (password.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter a password.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
      if (email.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        mypassword.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{
    return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is my form (inside a table)

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login/process.php" onsubmit="return ValidateLoginForm();">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><center><strong>Registration Form</strong></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password*</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" id="password" pattern=".{5,}" title="Minimum length of 5 letters or numbers."  required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Registration Form"></td>
<p>*Password must consist of numbers and letters.. 5 Characters minimum.</p>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are focusing a non-existent item `mypassword`, which causes your script to terminate in error and the form to submit normally.

```
if (email.value == "")
{
    alert("Please enter your email address.");
    // Focus the email rather than mypassword (which doesn't exist)
    email.focus();
    return false;
}
// All's well if you got this far, return true
return true;
```

[Here is the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/2fZAn/)

It is important to always develop JavaScript with your browser's error console open. You would have seen an error about an undefined object `mypassword`, which could point you to the faulty line in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. I just tried that but it still submits even with a blank email field. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @BobUni I was totally off.  Now I think I see the real source of the issue above...

Comment: Thanks Michael. That fixed it :-)

I didn't spot that and didn't realize it'd cause my script to terminate and submit.

Learn something new everyday!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without the html5 tags, using a common className, It would be

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login/process.php" onsubmit="return ValidateLoginForm();">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><center><strong>Registration Form</strong></center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input class="inputElement" type="text" name="username" id="username" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password*</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input class="inputElement" type="text" name="password" id="password" pattern=".{5,}" title="Minimum length of 5 letters or numbers."  ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input class="inputElement" type="text" name="email" id="email" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit Registration Form"></td>
<p>*Password must consist of numbers and letters.. 5 Characters minimum.</p>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

function ValidateLoginForm()
{
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('inputElement');;
    for(var i=0;i<inputElements.length;i++){
        if(!inputElements[i].value){
            alert(inputElements[i].name +' cannot be empty');
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```